# Using results of regression on raw observation values to approximate results of regression on relative change between observations (Simple, Linear)

Tags: regression, time-series, estimation, forecasting, approximation

this is my first time on Stack Exchange so if I did something wrong please tell me.

I have a time series dataset.
There is an observation $(y,x)$ for each continuous time $t$.
Let’s say for each day since 2014-01-01, i.e. $t \in \left\{0, 1, 2, …, 108 \right\}$, where $108$ means today.

I ran a regression on the model
$y = \alpha + \beta x$
and found $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $R^2 > 0.975$

My question is, can I **approximate** $\beta'$ in the model
$y' = \alpha' + \beta'x'$
where
$y'=\frac{y_{t+1}}{y_t}-1$
$x'=\frac{x_{t+1}}{x_t}-1$
**without** running regression on that model,

just by using $\hat{\beta'}= \frac{\beta \times x_{108}}{\hat{y_{108}}}$

where $\hat{y_{108}}$ is estimated using the original model.

I'm curious because I found that my $\hat{\beta'}$ is usually within 1% of $\beta'$

Even a simple Yes or No with help me a lot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "it depends".

It depends on what is the true process which generated this data, aka DGP (data generation process). Your approximation will not hold in a general case.

I'll give you an example.

Let's assume the true DGP: $\ln y_t=\alpha+\beta \ln x_t+\varepsilon_t$, where $\varepsilon_t\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma)$

Differenceing gives: $\Delta \ln y_{t+1}=\ln\frac{y_{t+1}}{y_{t}}=\beta\ln \frac{x_{t+1}}{x_t}+\Delta\varepsilon_{t+1}$

Since $\Delta \ln y_{t+1} \approx\frac{y_{t+1}}{y_{t}}-1=y_t'$, you get $y_t'=\beta x_t'+\Delta\varepsilon_{t}$

Now, if in your sample $x_t,y_t\sim 1$ then $\ln y_t\approx y_t-1$, , plugging this into DGP we get your model:

$y_t=\tilde{\alpha}+\beta x_t+\varepsilon_t$

So, my guess is that your $x_t,y_t$ happened to be close to 1, that's why it's working for you. Now that I wrote this all, I figured there's a simpler way to show this, but I'm too lazy to re-write it :)

Comment: Thanks! What if $y = \alpha + \beta x$ is the true DGP, and $x_t \sim 100, y_t \sim 2,500,000 $? How will the answer change?

Comment: If I regress $\ln y=\alpha''+\beta'' \ln x$, I get $\beta'' = 0.90\beta$

Comment: What are the variances?

Comment: $\sqrt{Var(x)} = 20, \sqrt{Var(y)} = 500,000$

Comment: You got lucky. It turns out that in your case $\Delta x_t/x_t\sim\Delta y_t/y_t$, look at the ratios of your dispersions and the variable levels.

Comment: If $y$ is price and $x$ is market index, can $\hat{\beta'}= \frac{\beta \times x_{108}}{\hat{y_{108}}}$ be interpreted in a way similar to the interpretation $\beta$ in CAPM?

Comment: In CAPM you regress the returns, not the prices. Prices and indices are nonstationary, you can't regress on on another.

Comment: Is regressing returns same as regressing $y' = \alpha' + \beta'x'$?

Comment: Yes, if you use simple returns. No if you use continuous compounding. We're now moving away from statistics into econometrics.

Comment: I tried regressing on returns of 15,000 assets separately and found that CAPM $\beta$ of an asset is within 0.05 of $\hat{\beta'}$ 95% of the time. Is it enough to justify the approximation?

Comment: What is your goal? You can't regress the prices on the index for many reasons. If you are working on CAPM then it's better to move the question to a different SE.

Comment: I have transaction records that are not continuous with respect to time, so I cannot generate the returns and regress returns on market returns. I found that regressing price on index has a fit of 0.975 to 0.999, so I generated synthetic transaction records that are continuous. On the other hand, Generating and regressing synthetic returns take time and CPU, so I was wondering if I can skip the part about regressing return on market return.

Comment: No, don't do this.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance! Do you have any recommended readings for obtaining Beta from incomplete time series of price?