# Approximated relation between the estimated coefficient of a regression using and not using log transformed outcomes

Tags: regression, approximation, logarithm

Consider the two regression equations:
\begin{align}
Y &= \alpha+\beta X+\varepsilon  \\
\log Y &= \gamma+\delta X+\eta
\end{align}
Is there a "simple" approximated relation between the coefficient estimated using the first equation ($\hat{\beta}$) and the one got by the second ($\hat{\delta}$) that can be used to get a sense of how approximately $\hat{\delta}$ looks like without running the regression? e.g. something like $\hat{\beta} \sim \hat{\delta}/\bar{Y}$, at least for some range of values of the variables or some hypothesis on the true DGP.

It was suggested to me by a fellow student, I cannot see why this should hold but I was not able to disprove it neither.

EDIT:
I found this other related question [Using results of regression on raw observation values to approximate results of regression on relative change between observations (Simple, Linear)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94365/using-results-of-regression-on-raw-observation-values-to-approximate-results-of), where the asker in the similar case in which the second model is a log-log:
$$
\log Y=\gamma+\delta \log X+\eta
$$
proposes the formula:
$$
\delta=\beta\times \frac{x_T}{\bar{y}}
$$
where I guess that $T$ is the last observation (it is a time series example). There is a similar answer to the one of Ami Tavory, but not much discussion too.

Answer (score 4):

> at least for some range of values of the variables

Say you start with

$$
Y=\alpha+\beta X+\varepsilon
$$

and

$$
\tag{1}
\log Y =\gamma+\delta X+\eta.
$$

Taking the exponent of both sides of (1), we get

$$
\tag{2}
Y = e^{\log Y} = e^{\gamma+\delta X+\eta}.
$$

*For small values of $y$*, we can use the [Taylor approximation of $e^x$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) on the RHS of (2):

$$
\tag{3}
Y \simeq 1 + \gamma + \delta X + \eta.
$$

So, if $Y$ takes small enough values in all of your dataset, you can apprximate $\gamma \sim 1 - \alpha$ and $\delta \sim \beta$.

Comment: Last sentence $1+\gamma \approx \alpha$, isn't it? And a capital $Y$ in eq. (3)?

Comment: Also, you needn't restrict yourself to $x \approx 0$: you could take the Taylor series around any arbitrary value of x and truncate to only the 0th and 1st order terms in order to obtain a linear approximation.

Comment: I don't think (3) is correct - it should be $ Y \approx e^{\gamma +\eta} + \delta e^{\gamma +\eta} X + \ldots$ .  This reveals a problem with this approximation - the shift from assumed additive noise to assumed multiplicative noise. This can be dealt with e.g. if we assume that the noise is Gaussian and $\eta$ is small wrt $\gamma$.

Comment: @Ami Tavory thanks for the answer, you mean for values of y near 1 not 0, right? the exponential approx works when the exponent is small, so when the log is small, that is y near 1.

Comment: @stuart10 could you elaborate a bit on your comment? why the approximation does not work when there is a stochastic term and how Gaussian noise can fix it?

Comment: @Matteo It depends on how you are fitting the regression coeffs. Say you are using a least squares fit for logY, that assumes the noise follows one of a family of distributions that includes Gaussian (but also others). That would imply noise on Y is lognormally distributed. If the sd of the lognormal is small wrt its mean then it can be reasonably approximated by a Gaussian. Similar arguments apply to (some?) other distributions for $\eta$ (with different levels of accuracy).

Comment: @Matteo The approximation above is based on the Taylor series and is valid when the quadratic (and higher order) terms in the series are negligible - i.e. when $X$ is near the value $a$ around which the series has been taken. This answer takes the Taylor series around $X=0$ (but is incorrect - see my comment above) so is valid for $X \approx 0$. You could equally well obtain the Taylor series for any other value of $X$, though the range over which the approximation becomes inaccurate will differ.